unity C# - wrong value updating with Time.deltaTime
I'm new to Unity and C# and trying to create a stamina bar for when player is sprinting.
public float sprintStaminaCurrent        = 1.0f;
public float sprintStaminaDrainPerSecond = 0.1f;
public float sprintStaminaGainPerSecond  = 0.02f;

//...

void Update()
{
    if(sprintStatus == true){
      sprintStaminaCurrent -= sprintStaminaDrainPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    }else{
      sprintStaminaCurrent += sprintStaminaGainPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
    }
    sprintbar.Value = sprintStaminaCurrent;
}

This code is working but the stamina drain is too slow.
I was expecting consume 0.1 per second, I mean, 10 seconds to get empty.
It's consuming something about 0.01 per second.
Am I doing something wrong with Time.deltaTime?

only if you changed the timescale

You don't seem to do something wrong with Time.deltaTime (unless timescal is changed as per previous comment). Maybe sprintStatus is changed elsewhere during execution? To eliminate this possibility, test your code removing the if else and the += part, keeping only the -= . And do a basic debug by printing sprintStaminaCurrent value at each step. You'll see if it's diminshing regularly by 0.1 each step

also check the sprintbar properties, what is the max and min values ?

Please check your variables in the Inspector. Since they are public, Unity serializes them, which means you might have overridden these values there, or altered the values in your file after Unity had already serialized them.

totally weird. I've commented all my code and tested removing comment from every each line. everything worked easy.

basically you made unity to reserialize the values. you could just change the values from the inspector window with the gameObject that has your script, selected.

Try to use a lerp.
‘’’
public float sprintStaminaCurrent        = 1.0f;
public float sprintStaminaDrainPerSecond = 0.1f;
public float sprintStaminaGainPerSecond  = 0.02f;

public float lerpCount = 0
//...

void Update()
{
    if(sprintStatus == true){
      sprintStaminaCurrent = Mathf.Lerp(0f, 1f, lerpCount);
      lerpCount += sprintStaminaDrainPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
     }else{
      sprintStaminaCurrent = Mathf.Lerp(1f, 0f, lerpCount);
      lerpCount -= sprintStaminaDrainPerSecond * Time.deltaTime;
     }
  sprintbar.Value = sprintStaminaCurrent;
 }

‘’’
